# All my <head> content is being rendered/outputted on <body>

Tags: php, wordpress

So this is my first post! I've just created the account, but I always check on here to solve my problems.
I've found others with the same problem but the solutions haven't been working for me.

So I have on the .PHP file all the content correctly placed on the head tag but for some reason it is going into the body tag leaving my first one empty.. And it adds a strange 
"

" (text space) on the beginning of the body.
What could it be?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> <?php if ( is_single() ) { ?> <?php } ?> <?php wp_title(); ?></title>
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress <?php bloginfo('version'); ?>">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" type="text/css" media="screen">
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS 2.0" href="<?php bloginfo('rss2_url'); ?>">
<link rel="alternate" type="text/xml" title="RSS .92" href="<?php bloginfo('rss_url'); ?>">
<link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="Atom 0.3" href="<?php bloginfo('atom_url'); ?>">
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback_url'); ?>">
</head>
<body>
```

Comment: Can you show the generated HTML source code? (use "View-source" option in your browser)

Comment: The code I've on the php is right there =)

Comment: Looking at the generated source I just found out that on the generated source the tags are on the right place, but on the developer tools and the page itself aren't outputting it correctly

Comment: Check your generated source for improperly closed tags and fix them, that should solve your problem.

Comment: @derik After reading your last comment: is your problem fixed?

Comment: Does the bloginfo() function use htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES); before returning result? a " could break html.

Comment: no it isn't. the page isnt rendering correctly. its like the generated source wont render it at the same way that when you view the page

Comment: I'm really not following what the validator is pointing out.. I get like 14 errors on the head, but I get things like "Line 2, Column 1: Non-space characters found without seeing a doctype first. Expected <!DOCTYPE html>.
<!DOCTYPE HTML>" What is wrong?

Comment: You are much more likely to get an answer rather than a total guess if you give a link to your site @derik. As a side note, you can remove <meta name="generator" content="WordPress <?php bloginfo('version'); ?>"> for security reasons and remove <?php if ( is_single() ) { ?> <?php } ?> as it's not doing anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely caused by an error introducing some text content into the head area.

It is very hard to identify where that is given the PHP instead of the generated HTML, but a [validator](http://validator.w3.org/) should pick it up.

Comment: I'm really not following what the validator is pointing out.. I get like 14 errors on the head, but I get things like "Line 2, Column 1: Non-space characters found without seeing a doctype first. Expected <!DOCTYPE html>.
<!DOCTYPE HTML>" What is wrong?

Comment: You have characters which are not spaces before the doctype. They might be non-printing characters that don't show up by default in your editor.

Comment: The validator picked up that the files had BOM.

Answer (score 5):

Easy Solution

1. Open your head containing file with Notepad++
2. Click on encoding, select Encode in UTF-8 Without BOM
   It fixes the issue.

Comment: Will having all of my other files (besides the head file) encoded in UTF-8 with BOM cause any problems? And, is there any way to batch convert all of the files to UTF-8 without BOM?

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution of this issues is, first open your header.php with (NotePad++ Windows application, or any software that you use for programming PHP files) and move to menu (Encoder) and set (Encoder UTF-8 (sans BOM)).

I have the same problem before but I'm trying to fix it by deleting JS and CSS files and the problem still not fixed.

Answer (score 1):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP.)*

Fixed. The problem was that the files were with BOM (Byte-Order Mark). Re-saving all files without the BOM solved it.